# Selection of points to a new layer in MeshLab

Tags: point-clouds, meshlab

I am working with some LiDAR data on MeshLab and I am looking for a way to select a chunk of vertices and transfer them to a new layer.

I know that you can move a selection of faces to a new layer but I do not have a mesh - only points.

Is there a workaround to do the same with vertices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a "Move selected vertices to another layer" filter in the "Mesh Layer" category.